# Ошибка из книги mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 mysqli_result boolean

Tags: php

По учебнику Бейли и Морриссона "Изучаем РНР и МySQL" в 8 главе получился код, который выдаёт ошибку:

"mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in"

даже после того, как полностью копирую код из учебника НИЧЕГО НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ (возможно дело в OpenServer).
Оригинальная ссылка на файлы [(ошибка у меня выходит в файле quetionnaire.php)](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/code/HeadFirstPHPMySQL_code_ch08.zip)

Что сделать, чтобы не было этой ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка говорит о том, что результат был вернут false вместо mysqli_result. Что в свою очередь говорит о том, что запрос не был выполнен http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php. После mysqli_query() лучше проверить что пришло и если там false, то вывести ошибку или записать ее в лог.

Comment: Там, в той ссылке, непонятно как проверять что за ошибка. Вставлять что ли тот большой код, где ещё какая-то "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ..." проводится?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки нашёл. Несколько разных ошибок были в коде автора книги.